# How can I see if or when someone has disabled my Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

Sometimes I notice some of my Azure Functions are disabled. I publish a new version to this slot a few times a day, and everyone in my team has access to it. Unfortunately, I have no idea who to ask "Hey, why did you disable that!".

Does anyone know where I can find this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check this information from Activity log of azure function. But the limitation here is that, the activity log records who / when modified your azure function, but it does not specify the details like disable/enable, you need to determine by yourself.

Here are the steps:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your function app -> Platform features -> Activity log:

[image]

2.Then in Activity log -> set the proper time range and other conditions, in the result, you can check the **operation name == Update web sites config** which indicates who modify your function including disable/enable operations, then check the **Event initiated by ** column to see who did the operation:

[image]

**Note:** For other readers, there is a few minutes delay between an operation being performed and it appearing in this list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For other readers, there is a few minutes delay between an operation being performed and it appearing in this list. Maybe you could add that to you answer @Ivan, but otherwise this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @lemon_grab, yes, I added it in the note section:).

Comment: Ivan you said "but it does not specify the details like disable/enable, you need to determine by yourself." - any pointers on how?  Can extra logging be enabled or anything setup that gives more information as to WHAT changed rather than just the general WHO/WHEN? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution for your issue can be solved by *Azure Event Grid* with subscribing to the specific resource group and pushing the events to your e-mail account, etc.

In your case, when the azure function config has been changed, the resource group event is generated with the following subject:

```
 "eventType":"Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess",
 "subject":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myFncApp/config/appSettings",
```

and in the event data claims object are details who made this changes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't want to do any development for this, however it may be useful for others.